# Validate Swagger API Declaration using official Swagger API schema

Tags: json, json.net, swagger

The swagger-spec repository provides a [JSON-schema](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-spec/blob/master/schemas/v2.0/schema.json) describing a valid Swagger 2.0 API definition.
I would like to use this schema in order to validate if a given API definition file is valid before I try to interpret it.
I'm using the following code to load the schema using Json.NET:

```
JsonSchema swaggerApiSchema;
using (var textReader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(@"C:\path\to\schema.json")))
{
    swaggerApiSchema = JsonSchema.Read(textReader);
}
```

This throws an ArgumentException reporting "Can not convert Array to Boolean.".

Is there something wrong with the schema file, is this a bug with Json.NET, or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per documentation, JSON.NET implements JSON Schema Draft 3. More [here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/JsonSchema.htm). But the Swagger schema you posted is created according to the JSON Schema Draft 4. One of the differences between the Draft 3 and Draft 4 of the JSON Schema is the required attribute, which in JSON Schema Draft 3 was an attribute of subschemas in properties. In JSON Schema Draft 4 is a first level keyword playing the same role, and has a string array as an argument.

**Sample of JSON Schema Draft 3:**

```
{
    "properties": {
        "Id": {
            "required": true,
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "FirstName": {
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
        },
        "LastName": {
            "required": true,
            "type": "string
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample of JSON Schema Draft 4:**

```
{
    "properties": {
        "Id": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "FirstName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "LastName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [ "Id", "FirstName", "LastName" ]
}
```

Notice the difference in the two schemas, of how required properties are defined. That's why you are getting an error: "Can not convert Array to Boolean.".

And here is the first appearance of required property in the Swagger JSON Schema, that is causing the error:

```
"required": [ "swagger", "info", "paths" ]
```

I would suggest to validate with parser that implements JSON Schema Draft 4.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! Do you have a suggestion for a parser that I could use for the validation?

Comment: I'm currently testing with a fork of Newtonsoft Json library, https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/pull/328 .  We are still waiting on JameNK to resolve merge conflicts to incorporate schema v4 into the main branch.